# Javascript/jquery суммирование по чекбоксу в ячейку

Tags: javascript, jquery

я практически не знаком с javascript/ jquery ( уровень знаний минимальный). Нужно сделать задачу

Есть три ячейки чекбоса ( с задаными числами/ценами, отобразил в переменных скрипта JS, или можно отобразить в дата атрибутах чекбокса/лейбла к нему?) и одна ячейка вывода. Задача: Что бы все отмеченные чекбоксы суммировались в ячейку суммы. Если чекбокс снят, что бы происходил перерасчет. Может кто отредактировать скрипт на это ? ( щас скрипт тупо делает сумму по заданным 3 переменным без привязки к состояниям чекбокса). Что-то на подобии if (checkBox.checked == true){
запустить суммирование этого элемента в ячейку суммы (чекбокс 1 это переменная JS число 1, и т.д.);

Помогите пожалуйста

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this calculates values automatically 
  sum();
  $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    sum();
  });
});

function sum() {
  var num1 = 500;
  var num2 = 600;
  var num3 = 700;

  var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + parseInt(num3);
  var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Num 1:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="num1" id="num1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Num 2:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="num2" id="num2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Num 3:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="num3" id="num3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: ссылка на кодпен https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKxjaB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKbqdo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  sum();
  $(':checkbox').change(sum);
});

function sum() {
  var data = {
    num1: 500,
    num2: 600,
    num3: 700
  }

  //получаем массив ключей из чекнутых чекбоксов
  var keys = $(':checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('name');
  });

  var result = 0;
  $.each(keys, function( index, key ) {
    var value = parseInt(data[key]) || 0;
    result += value;
  });

  document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, супер!, а то у меня бы ушел целый день на это(или даже больше)

Comment: @IvanP зато в следующий раз ушло бы полдня. А в следующий раз, пара часов, а потом вообще 10 минут. А если не будете этим заниматься, то так и будет уходить по целому дню!

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Абсолютно верно, сейчас просто нужен срочный результат по проекту (это один из последних 2 костылей). Параллельно с этим учу javascript и пытаюсь разобраться.